# Hash: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

In ruby if I have a CSV file called, vehicles.csv:

```
make,model,color,doors           
dodge,charger,black,4           
ford,focus,blue,5             
nissan,350z,black,2                          
mazda,miata,white,2            
honda,civid,brown,4           
corvette,stingray,red,2            
ford,fiesta,blue,5
```

This is my code:

```
require "csv"
file = CSV.open("vehicles.csv", headers: :first_row).map(&:to_h)
puts file["make"]
```

I turn this csv file into a hash and then try to output one of the keys of the hash but keep getting "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" what must be done? I am trying to get something that looks like this as the output:

```
dodge
ford
nissan
mazda
honda
corvette
ford
```

Comment: You have applied `map` to your `CSV` object. This returns an `Array`, and you need integer indices to access the array elements. See [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Enumerable.html#method-i-map),

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file = CSV.open("vehicles.csv", headers: :first_row).map(&:to_h)`
leaves file as an array of hashes.  Try this to see what I mean.

```rb
require "csv"
file = CSV.open("vehicles.csv", headers: :first_row).map(&:to_h)
puts file.class
puts file.first.class
puts file.first
puts file.map {_1["make"]}
```

Another way to accomplish what you want is read the csv file into a table and then use the values_at method to get all the data in a given column

```rb
file = CSV.open("vehicles.csv", headers: :first_row)
table = file.read
puts table.values_at("make")
```